# modern proof of the conditional three prime theorem by Hardy and Littlewood

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Hardy and Littlewood proved the three prime theorem under the GRH(generalized Riemann hypothesis) in an old paper:
*Some problems of `Partitio numerorum'; III: On the expression of a number as a sum of primes*. Acta Math. 44 (1923), no. 1, 1–70.

The proof is long with old notations. Is there a modern reference for their proof? I mean, modern people should be able to simplify their proof to make it shorter than Vinogradov's unconditional proof given in Nathanson's *Additive Number Theory* textbook. My main focus is: how does GRH help in simplifying Vinogradov's proof? I heard that with GRH, the estimate for minor arc is much simpler but I don't know the details.

Comment: Couldn't the Yitang Zhang bound between primes be used as a modern sledgehammer?  There are infinite prime gaps of 246 or less.  Doesn't that lead to an easy proof that googolplex+1 is the sum of 3 primes?